# How change varchar and date to timestamp Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

in raport I create, I take data and separate hour in varchar. I must concat that and change type to timestamp

date from user '20220323' in data type
hour from user '12:01:02' in string

and i must use this in where

where timestamp = date||' ' ||hour||,000000000

my format timestamp is '22/03/23 12:01:02,123456789'

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `TO_TIMESTAMP()` to convert string to datetime.
Credit to VBoka for his help.
See below for format string parameters.

> ```
> create table source_of_data (user_date date, user_hours varchar(100))
> ```

> ```
> insert into source_of_data values(to_date('20220323', 'yyyymmdd'),  '12:01:02');
> ```

> ```
> select to_timestamp(to_char(user_date, 'yyyymmdd') || ' ' || user_hours ,'YYYYMMDD HH24:MI:SS') as_timestamp
> from source_of_data;
> ```
>
> ```
> | AS_TIMESTAMP                 |
> | :--------------------------- |
> | 23-MAR-22 12.01.02.000000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=627edac57b8a6252190f2db6dc4b3354)*

```
Parameter   Explanation

YYYY        4-digit year
MM          Month (01-12; JAN = 01).
MON         Abbreviated name of month.
MONTH       Name of month, padded with blanks to length of 9 characters.
DD          Day of month (1-31).
HH          Hour of day (1-12).
HH12        Hour of day (1-12).
HH24        Hour of day (0-23).
MI          Minute (0-59).
SS          Second (0-59).
```

Comment: I would like to give my contribution to this answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=627edac57b8a6252190f2db6dc4b3354 I believe OP asked to concatenate DATE type and VARCHAR type into TIMESTAMP "How change varchar and date to timestamp Oracle" and because of that I added a date column and added to_char function. Cheers

Comment: Work perfect :) Thanks

Comment: `HH` should be `HH24` or have `AM` component to identify time of a day.

Comment: @astentx : Thank you - when I tested with 18:00 I get an error so I have corrected.